# UnicodeDecodeError open python file with windows command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, command-prompt

I have a script that called runsplit.py it looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('final.txt', 'w')

import re
with open('a.txt') as f:
 new_split = [item.strip() for item in f.readlines()]

for word in new_split:
 m = re.match(r"(?:\{[^-#={}/|]+\})?(?:([^-#={}/|]+)-)?([^-#={}/|]+)(?:/[^-#={}/|]+)?(?:[#=]([^-#={}/|]+))?", word)
if m:
    print("\t".join([str(item).lstrip() for item in m.groups()]))
else:
    print("(no match: %s)" % word)
```

and I have a text file called a.txt which I want to split in final.txt file but a.txt file has some characters like ⁱ and ǐ in it that made error when I run the script in command prompt the error said this:

```
File "runsplit_in_terminal.py", line 9, in <module>
print("\t".join([str(item).lstrip() for item in m.groups()]))
File "C:\Users\Sina\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x94' in position 10: character maps to 
<undefined>
```

is there any advice to solve this issue thanks.

Comment: Please don't tag your IDE or code editor unless your question is specifically related to the editor itself.

Answer (score -1):

You may try opening the text file with **Unicode Text Format** by adding the parameter `encoding = 'utf-8'` in the `open()` function.

Example:`f=open('hii.txt',encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: The problem in the traceback clearly indicates that it's the _output_ which is problematic, because their console is set to cp1252.

Comment: thanks @srikesh I am new in python so I have tried your solution but it still says error can you please explain a bit what part of my script should I wrote   f=open('hii.txt',encoding='utf-8') that work properly thanks.

Comment: It is caused due to that when the `open()` function is executed , the contents in the files is converted into the the ASCII in which the string manipulations cannot be done with that , So you should convert into UTF-8 so that it will read the read the contents of the file as raw without ASCII ,then you can do string manipulations and other things.Kindly upvote and mark my answer as correct.....   @Arman.

Comment: I have tried your solution but that doesn't work @Srikesh